# Где используют Node.js

Tags: node.js

Для чего лучше всего подходит Node.js? Для многопользовательской браузерной игры подойдет? Да и вообще для чего его используют?

Answer (score 1):

Для броузерной игры - можно. Вот Вконтакт на нем [сделал](http://www.insight-it.ru/masshtabiruemost/arkhitektura-vkontakte/) jabber сервер. [mail.ru](http://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/141361/) и себе сделал почту на нем.

А некоторые даже делают на базе него [движок для win приложений](http://habrahabr.ru/post/168225/).

То есть, использовать можно для много чего, было бы желание, идеи и знания javascript.

Answer (score 0):

я вот писал робота и веб-морду к нему. отлично работает

Answer (score 0):

сейчас пишу на ноде многопользовательскую браузерную игрушку, а точнее экшн-часть, в связке с SockJS для рил-тайма